# Placing label on map once in TileMill?

Tags: tilemill, mapbox, cartocss

I am trying to create a basemap in tilemill.  Very new to this software.  When I add the label styling for the roads, it adds the name several times.  Is there a way to have it only place the label on the map once?

My code

```
#MajorRoads{
  [STREET_NAM='NC-191']{
   text-name:[STREET_NAM];
   text-face-name:'Arial Regular';
   line-width:3;
   line-color:#606060;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the `text-spacing` property, which controls 'distance between repeated text labels on a line (aka. label-spacing)'. Here's a link to the CartoCSS docs:

https://github.com/mapbox/carto/blob/master/docs/latest.md#text-spacing-unsigned

You can also find some other helpful properties there for label placement, including  `text-placement` and `text-min-path-length`.